# How to get a difference between 2 different date datatypes in MS sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two columns  EnrollmentStartDate and EligibilityStartDate and I need to get a difference between the two (enroll - elibil) and then get the average number of days it takes for a client to become active from eligibility date.

The problem is EnrollmentStartDate in one of the tables is in *datetime2* format while EligibilityStartDate in the other table is in *date* format.

and I'm getting the following error

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator.

Is there a way to convert one into another? how do I go about this?

```
    select clientid, avg(EnrollmentStartDate - EligibilityStartDate) as avg_daysFROM dbo.Client  inner join  dbo.ClientEnrollment ON dbo.Client.ClientId = dbo.ClientEnrollment.ClientId order by avg_days
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF()` should be able to handle this:

```
select clientid,
       avg(datediff(day, EligibilityStartDate, EnrollmentStartDate) * 1.0
          )
. . .
```

The `* 1.0` is so the average is not calculated as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not perform arithmetic subtract operation on DATE and
   DATETIME2 datatypes. You have to rather use DATEDIFF function in SQL
   Server.
2. You need a GROUP BY if you are bringing in any column in the SELECT along with using aggregate function
3. Also, would recommend you to use alias names in tables when there
   are more than one tables involved in a query for better readability.

Assuming EnrollmentStartDate and EligibilityStartDate columns are in dbo.ClientEnrollment table,

```
SELECT  C.ClientId
        ,avg_days = AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, CE.EligibilityStartDate, CE.EnrollmentStartDate)) 
FROM    dbo.Client C
        INNER JOIN  dbo.ClientEnrollment CE
            ON C.ClientId = CE.ClientId 
GROUP   BY C.ClientId           
ORDER   BY avg_days
```